# Javascript RegExpression

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking for a regular expression that will accept date formats, both MM/DD/YYYY and M/D/YYYY

I found one [here](http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=1071)

However when I run that I get an unexpected illegal token.  Here is how I am implementing the javascript function

```
return RegExp(/^(((0?[1-9]|1[012])/(0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])|(0?[13456789]|1[012])/(29|30)|(0?[13578]|1[02])/31)/(19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}|0?2/29/((19|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(([2468][048]|[3579][26])00)))$/).test(txtDate);
```

I've been told the http://regexlib.com website usually works well for .net regular expressions, but not javascript.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape the slashes inside the regex.

```
/^(((0?[1-9]|1[012])\/(0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])|(0?[13456789]|1[012])\/(29|30)|(0?[13578]|1[02])\/31)\/(19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}|0?2\/29\/((19|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(([2468][048]|[3579][26])00)))$/
             here __^                                         __^                        __^ ___^                   ___^___^
```

Comment: I'm a newbie to this can I do that with the "\"

Comment: @JonHarding: Just insert a backslash `\` before each slash `/` as shown in my answer.

Comment: I just realized this regex only goes back to 1900, any ideas on a quick fix?

Comment: @JonHarding: I'm afraid there's no quick way to fix it. The regex will become very complicated.

Answer (score 0):

for MM/DD/YY `/^(\d{1,2})[./-](\d{1,2})[./-](\d{4})$/`

for M/D/Y `/^(\d{1,2})[./-](\d{1,2})[./-](\d{2}|\d{4})$/`

Answer (score 0):

Recipe 4.4 from [Regex Cookbook](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596520694.do) does most of what you are looking for:

```
^(1[0-2]|0?[1-9])/(3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])/(?:[0-9]{2})?[0-9]{2}$
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/32JQr/

hope this helps